# What is the difference between jQuery rails(2.2.1) and browser's jQuery(1.8.3)?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, browser, rubygems

i am new to ruby on rails, i installed latest gem jQuery rails(2.2.1) but the browser jQuery version is 1.8.3 why it's different

Answer (score 0):

jquery-rails gem version has nothing to do with the jquery library version. jquery-rails gem only supports you rails specific stuff like asset pipeline support and so on.. the jquery-rails gem contains the jquery library..normally the latest jquery-rails version contains the latest jquery library. but version number is not dependent on each other.

Comment: thanks for the information, but while using jQuery 1.8.3 there is some sort of flickering(goes down and aligned in a fraction of second) in firefox browser when i add jQuery 1.9.1 there is no flickering in firefox browser